# How to align text appended to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jscrollpane, text-alignment

I think the screenshot is worth a couple of paragraphs

[image: screenshot of the text alignment problem]

The best way I can think of doing it is to check for the length of the string and depending give/take `\t`, but it just seems inelegant. Is there a simpler/better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a JTable for this. You can put one in a JScrollPane. This will get you aligned columns automatically. Plus you will get column headers which will aid in understanding what the data means.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with plain text and have an upper bound on the length of fields (which you'd need to guarantee alignment), then you could use printf.